# Does AEON offer a sweep transaction feature?

Tags: aeon, sweep-transaction

I found these [sweep transaction instructions](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/3507/what-is-a-sweep-input-and-how-do-they-work) for Monero but cannot find anything similar for AEON. Does a similar feature exist? If not what is the AEON strategy for dealing with lots of dust generated from mining payments or many other small transactions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now, with release 0.9.8.0, it isn't possible, as there's no equivalent sweep command in Aeon's CLI.

I asked your question on Slack today, and this is what moneromooo had to say on the topic:

> I think it's fairly new in monero. I also think it relies on the new tx composition algorithm, so not an easy port.
>
> It'd be possible to add a function to do this using the previous algorithm, but it's less well suited and might well fail pretty often, which makes it not very useful.

Hope this answers your question.